# How to use all my data from Google Earth on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-earth, import, qgis-3

So my problem is this : I been working in Google Earth for 4 years, and always lacked something, last week I found out about QGIS and started experimenting with it. It have much more tools than GE and I wish to transfer all my old progress from Google Earth to my QGIS Version 3.2 Bonn. Is there any way that I can import all my polygons(fields), lines(rivers,roads) into QGIS so I can continue my work with QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGis can easily import kml/kmz-files. Just make sure to save them as shapefile or geopackages before beginning to edit them.

Everything in GE "my places" can be saved as kml/kmz.

Comment: Hy Erik thanks for answering! Can you describe to me process of Importing KML/KMZ into QGIS i saved GE into KML/KMZ but if i try drag and drop it QGIS just do not respond, Do i just need to wait coz the KML is 329 MB and KMZ 97 MB?

Comment: I'd advise you to split your data in logical and/or spatial chunks. E.g. export all agricultural areas separately from all residential areas, and roads separate from railways etc. This will both speed up the loading in QGis and provide a much clearer data structure.

Comment: Alright, will do that but still u didn"t answer me do i need to use some of plugins? or just drag and drop files?

Comment: Ah, sorry: Yes, you simply drag & drop. Especially kmz is a lot more compressed than shapefiles, thus leading to a long loading time.